# Eclipse & Android Emulator Windows vs Linux

Tags: android, linux, eclipse, android-emulator

I've noticed that when I'm running eclipse and emulator under windows system (both XP and 7), in 1-2 hours it eats in total of 950Mb of memory (almost 700Mb goes to eclipse according to the task manager). Is it normal? Will it be reasonable to move android development environment to Linux system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not biased towards one or the other, but Android anything always runs better on Linux. I have never liked memory management or GC in the JVM's on Windows